# Деление числа на два слагаемых

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык

Суть задачи в том что бы получить число которое в сумме с собой перевернутым даст x (любой длинны)
например x = 143 ответ: 49+94

```
import math

def inv(n):
    r = str(n)
    return int(r[::-1])

x = int(input())
y = -1
for i in range(abs(int(math.sqrt(x))),int(x // 2)):
    if i + inv(i) == x:
        y = i
        break
print(y)
```

Моя попытка работает слишком долго, возможно ли это оптимизировать?

Comment: Числа двухзначные только или любые?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, скорее всего любые.

Comment: Можно анализировать поразрядно число. берем старший разряд и пробуя 10 цифр вычисляем младший. учитываем при этом возможные переносы в следующий. когда подобрали, сдвигаемся к середине (помня переносы) и повторяем ту же процедуру. по моему представлению должно получиться и сложность будет около O=10*log10(N). Если число начинается на 1 (как в нашем случае) так же пробуем старшим разрядом считать 14 и повторяем то же для чисел на 1 разряд короче. К сожалению сегодня не будет времени попробовать идею самому

Answer (score 1):

Какое ограничение на длину числа?

Исходя из этой длины, можно выразить искомое число и перевернутое как совокупность цифр (полином по базе 10)

```
x = 10 * a + b
x' = 10 * b + a 
x + x' = 11*a + 11*b = 11 * (a+b) = 143
a + b = 143 / 11 =  13
```

Таким образом, решениями являются пары цифр, дающие в сумме 13: 49; 58; 67

Заметьте, что далеко не все числа можно выразить в виде такой суммы

Comment: А если трехзначные, то как действовать? `100A+10B+C + 100C+10B+A = 101A + 20B + 101C` И что с этим выражением делать? Его никак не сократить, множитель не вынести. Легко только для двухзначных, к сожалению...

Comment: В общем случае  - получать все решения целочисленного уравнения (линейное диофантово уравнение). Это позволяет на порядок сократить перебор. Для первой и последней цифр можно еще заметить, что `(a+c) = N % 10` или `10 + N % 10`

Answer (score 1):

Подойдем к задаче аналитически. Рассмотрим особенности сумм двух зеркально отраженных чисел. Если бы не возникали эффекты от переноса разрядов, то сумма так же была бы зеркальной. Если сумма не зеркальна, значит в ней возникли переносы, которые изменили более старшие разряды при переполнении в младших. В самый младший разряд числа переносов заведомо не было. Все остальные разряды могут содержать перенос. Перенос может либо отсутствовать, либо быть равным 1. Таким образом любой разряд из старшей половины числа равен, либо на 1 больше, зеркальному ему разряду из младшей части, при условии, что из младшего разряда уже удалили возможный перенос в него. Мы можем узнать был ли перенос при сложении самого старшего разряда. Если он был, то число будет начинаться на 1 этого самого переноса. Перенос в старшем разряде мог произойти при сложении двух цифр дающих в результате число >10. Либо он может возникнуть в случае, если сумма в старшем разряде была 9 и в него произошел перенос из предыдущего разряда. Учтя данные факторы мы можем точно узнать создало ли сложение в старшем разряде перенос. Если он был, то перенос был и при сложении самого младшего разряда. Зная это можно узнать во первых все варианты первого и последнего разрядов, а во вторых, происходил ли перенос из второго с начала и во второй с конца разряды. Т.е. получить те же вводные данные для дальнейшего расчета, какие были при анализе крайних разрядов.

С учетом вышесказанного мы можем, двигаясь от старшего разряда к центральному, подбирать варианты одного, конкретного разряда и вычислять симметричный ему. После чего объединить результаты уже при печати. Если перебор одного разряда считать полным (от 0 до 9) то сложность алгоритма получается **максимум `O=5*log10(N)`**, где N искомая сумма.

Реализация алгоритма на языке perl (алгоритм можно было выполнить циклом, но рекурсией мне показалось нагляднее):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $x=143;

test_digit($x,0,0);
if($x=~/^1(\d+)/) {  # Число начинается на 1, возможно это был перенос
  test_digit($1,1,0); # анализируем число без старшей 1, с флагом наличия переноса
}

sub test_digit {
  my($x,$lo,$ro,$vars)=@_;
  # x - Число
  # lo - Признак переноса ИЗ старшего разряда,
  # ro - Признак переноса В младший разряд
  # vars - Массив вариантов предыдущих разрядов
  $vars//=[]; # Массив не передан, считаем пустым
  $x="1$x"; # добавляем запасной разряд, что бы ведущий ноль не был отброшен
  $x-=$ro; # Коррекция переноса в правом разряде
  $x=~s/^1//; # убираем запасной разряд
  if(length($x)==1) { # Одна цифра в середине числа
    return if($x % 2); # Она не четная - некоррекная сумма зеркальных чисел
    $x+=10 if($lo); # Учет переноса из старшего разряда
    push @$vars, [[$x/2]];
    return print_result("","",@$vars);
  }
  my($l, $nx, $r)= $x=~/^(.)(.*)(.)/;  # левый и правый разряды, nx-середина числа
  my($nlo,$nro)=(0,0);  # Флаги наличия переносв для анализа следующей пары разрядов
  if($l==($r+1)) {  # Левый разряд на 1 больше, значит он получал перенос
    $l--;
    $nlo=1; # Запоминаем факт прихода переноса
  } elsif($l==0 && $r==9 && $lo) { # Перенос левого разряда вызван переносом из предыдущего
    $l=9; $lo=0; $nlo=1;
  } elsif($l!=$r) { # Разряды не могут быть не равны, число не является подходящей суммой
    return;
  }
  if($lo) { # Есть перенос в левом разряде
    $nro=$lo; # Значит и в правом он был
    $l+=10;
  }
  push @$vars, generate_vars($l);  # Заполняем массив вариантов
  if(length($nx)) { # Мы еще не достигли середины, анализируем следующую пару разрядов
    test_digit($nx, $nlo, $nro, $vars);
  } else {
    return print_result("","",@$vars);
  }
}
# Генерация всех вариантов слагаемых для указанной суммы
sub generate_vars {
  my $n=shift;
  my @vars;
  for(my $i=0; $i<=9 && $i<=$n; $i++) {
    push @vars, [$i, $n-$i] if($n-$i<=9);
  }
  return \@vars;
}
# Распечатка возможных вариантов
sub print_result {
  my($l,$r,@vars)=@_;
  my $v=shift @vars;
  for(@$v) {
    if(@vars) {
      print_result($l.$_->[0],$_->[1].$r,@vars);
    } else {
      print $l,$_->[0],$_->[1],$r,"\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**VBA**

Находим одну подходящую пару или сообщаем о проколе

```
Sub ReversValue()
Dim a As Long, i As Long
    a = 99

    For i = 1 To Int(a / 2)
        If Len(i) = Len(a) Then
            If a - StrReverse(i) = i Then  Then MsgBox i & "+" & a - i: Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox "нет"
End Sub
```

- достаточно просмотреть половину значений (*a / 2*)
- часть проверок исключается сравнением разрядности (*Len(i) = Len(a)*)